# How can i get version number of jar and update version number in startup script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have created RPM and RPM included Jar file. I have startup script which it will execute Jar file.

I have created startup script and included jar file name and path to execute.
But Jar file has version number, which it will changes for every new build.
I need to update that version number in my script.How can i do it?
Ex : Jar file --- sample-1.0.2.jar
In script, i gave PATH_TO_JAR=/opt/sample.jar, but this sample.jar is not executing due to version number.

My startup script in /opt/bin folder. while executing my script, PATH_TO_JAR=/opt/sample-1.0.2.jar has to updated with version.
How can i update the jar version number in my script?

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want the script to automatically select the most recent version of the jar in your directory? Are you looking for an automated way to change the script as part of "deploying" a new version of the jar?

Comment: Yes!!! I am looking for script or command to update Jar version at PATH_TO_JAR. Then, jar file will be executed with Java -jar command in my script. Jar file is  in /opt directory and script is in /opt/bin. How can i get version of Jar?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem boils down to sorting `jar`s by their version string. Here's an example command line snippet that extracts the jar with the latest version number.

Assuming you have two files, you can't just `sort` them lexicographically:

```
sample-10.0.2.jar
sample-2.3.4.jar
```

Here `ls -1` puts them in the files in the order given above, because `10` comes before `2` alphabetically.

Assuming the files don't contain spaces, here's a portable way to sort by the version string

```
ls -1 | awk -F- '{print $2 " " $0}' | sort -t. -n -k1,3 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Breaking that down a bit, this fragment produces the following:

```
ls -1 | awk -F- '{print $2 " " $0}'
```

extracts everything after the `-` and prints it as the first "word" of the line.

```
10.0.2.jar sample-10.0.2.jar
2.3.4.jar sample-2.3.4.jar
```

This is a numeric `sort` in the first three fields.

```
sort -t. -n -k1,3
```

We actually want to reverse this though, so the largest version number is at the top, and then we want to grab the first item. We can reverse the sort by passing `-r` to `sort` and grab the first field of the first item with `awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}'`

```
ls -1 | awk -F- '{print $2 " " $0}' | sort -t. -n -r -k1,3 | awk 'NR == 1 {print $2}'
```

Which gives us

```
sample-10.0.2.jar
```

So, putting it all together here's a script you can source in order to update the `PATH_TO_JAR` environment variable

Hypothetical `update-path.sh` script

```
# update path to jar, look at all .jar files in /opt
# find the one with the largest version string (assuming three components)
jar_name=$(ls -1 /opt/*.jar | \
    awk -F- '{print $2 " " $0}' | \
    sort -t. -n -r -k1,3 | \
    awk 'NR == 1 {print $2}')
PATH_TO_JAR=/opt/"$jar_name"
export PATH_TO_JAR
```

To use it, `. update-path.sh` or `source update-path.sh`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed script. In my directory, every time i will have only one jar. So no need to go for sorting. I just want to pick that jar version into my script. When i created new RPM through my job, Jar version was updated with build number as a version. If i install that RPM on my machine, Jar file extracted into directory. I will modify the script according to my requirement and will use it. Thanks again!!!